# Order an array based in another array and replace no matching data with 0 or empty string javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array that defines the order of data to draw in a chart.

The data comes in another array. I have a function that sort the data array based on the order array but I need to add a 0 or an empty string if the data does have data in the particular item or the order array.

My example is:

Order array:

```
const tooltipsLabel = [
  "02 Abril 2021",
  "03 Abril 2021",
  "04 Abril 2021",
  "05 Abril 2021",
  "06 Abril 2021",
  "07 Abril 2021",
  "08 Abril 2021"
]
```

Data Array:

```
const dayData = {
     01 Abril 2021: (2) [{…}, {…}],
     04 Abril 2021: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
     05 Abril 2021: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}],
     06 Abril 2021: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
     07 Abril 2021: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}],
     08 Abril 2021: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
   }
```

As you can see, there is no data for 02 and 03 Abril 2021.

My actual sorting functions is this:

```
const mapOrder = (array, order, key) => {
            array.sort(function (a, b) {
                var A = a[key],
                    B = b[key];

                if (order.indexOf(A) > order.indexOf(B)) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            });
            console.log(array);
            return array;
        };
```

and I call the function like this:

```
mapOrder(Object.entries(dayData),tooltipsLabel,day[0]);
```

It sorts my data but I need 0 or empty for 02 and 03 Abril 2021 and just like an additional point, I just need the length of the data for every date in the array.

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The data is what I wrote in the two arrays and my expected out is something like [08 Abril 2021: 6, 07 Abril 2021: 3, 06 Abril 2021: 7, 05 Abril 2022: 3, 04 Abril 2021: 7, 03 Abril 2021: 0, 02 Abril 2021: 0, 01 Abril 2021: 2]. If the answer could be just [6,3,7,3,7,0,0,2] keeping the order but only de lenghts will be ideal.

Comment: You can simply sort your `tooltipsLabel` array as you want, and then `map()` it to retrieve elements from the `dayData` array. `const result = tooltipsLabel.map(day => dayData[day]?.length ?? 0);`

Comment: Jimmy Montes, Does @pilchard answer solve your  problem?

Comment: @Nur Yeap, it totally works just how I need it

Comment: Thanks @pilchard for your time and your great response.